# How do i get two decimal fraction from this sum?

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code:

```
int a = Convert.ToInt16(FractionSum1);
int b = Convert.ToInt16(s1);
int c = (a / b) + 1;
DecimalBox.Text = c.ToString("#.00");
DecimalBox.Update();
```

in this case `a = 11` and `b = 2`, the answer I am trying to get is `6.50` but its outcome always shows `6`.

what am I doing wrong? I have tried ToInt32 seems to make no difference, can anybody help?

Comment: You should be using doubles. If you do integer arithmetic 11/2 is 5 not 5.5

Comment: I've not used doubles before, where would I find out what to change my code to?